# iis express client certificate invalid cert

Tags: authentication, .net-core, iis-express

I'm developing a dotnetcore 2.0 mvc application which requires a client-certificate to be included.

I created Root CA Trusted certificate AND Revocation Cert which are installed in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities of LocalMachine.

makecert -n "CN=RootCaTest" -r -sv RootCaTest.pvk RootCaTest.cer
makecert -crl -n "CN=RootCaTest" -r -sv RootCaTest.pvk RootCaTest.crl

I then used that RootCaTest cert to create a Client-Certificate:
makecert -sk user -iv RootCaTest.pvk -n "CN=usercert" -ic RootCaTest.cer -sr currentuser -ss my -sky signature -pe

In IIS-Express applicationHost.config, i have set (as per other articles)

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <access sslFlags="Ssl, SslNegotiateCert" />
    ....
  </security>
  <authentication>
    <iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="true"></iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication>
    ....
  </authentication>
</system.webServer>
```

When I try to debug the application, I get an error that "Unable to start dotnet.exe. the server returned 403 error" - and that the full response was written to HttpFailure_xx.html.
the HttpFailure file shows that "Your client certificate is either not trusted or is invalid."

The error happens BEFORE the web-browser is opened for debug - Visual Studio 2017 shows a system-message with the error.

I have followed the instructions on that page which leads to verifying that "There are one or more non–self-signed certificates in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities certificate store. A non–self-signed certificate is any certificate for which the "Issued To" and "Issued By" values are not an exact match." - there are none after checking.

Without the above changes to iis-express config, Context.Connection.ClientCertificate is always null.

I have spent the past two days reading post after post about this, but I cannot find any solution that works in my case.

Note that I have checked that the ClientCertificate is send via HttpClient correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have concluded that the problem lies with the way debugging is configured.
Kestrel ListenOptions are configured for HTTPS and to include the specified Server Certificate AND Require Client Certificate for authentication.

If I change the application's Debug properties and switch 'Launch:' IIS-Express to Project, debugging now opens the Kestrel-server in a console-window (rather than the browser).

Now, if I make calls to the Kestrel-Urls, the Client-Certificate is no-longer null and I am able to validate the request etc.

When debugging in IIS-Express, I see that the server-certificate (in the browser) is 'localhost', NOT the one I specified in the Kestrel Listen-Options.

What I would like to know is:
Is it possible to somehow configure IIS-Express to use the same server-certificate as is set for Kestrel?
Or, is the only way to debug this application locally to launch the project?

Thanks

Comment: Did you figure out a solution to the IIS Express problem?